# CR adds spaces before accented characters

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Why is Crystal report showing spaces in front of accented characters? Can we correct this by any mean? I can't be removed by editing the label as it shows no accent. I suspect that it has something to do with double byte characters.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must change the Language property of the parent form of your CrystalReportViewer to the language you need to support (in my case, I changed it to "French (Canada)".

Visual Studio will create a language ressource file (DLL). Don't forget to distribute this file with your executable.

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that it's by changing the font size in the report that I corrected the bug.